# Eclipse, installed two Weblogic instances, can't login to another

Tags: eclipse, weblogic

I installed two Weblogic server instances on my workstation, and added them to Eclipse under servers tab. The instances are wls 11 and wls 12.

Now, after I installed the wls 12, I can not login to wls 11 admin console anymore, even I enter the valid credentials. It doesn't give any error message, just returns to the login screen. By inspecting the login request on developer console, I can see it's status: `Status Code:302 Moved Temporarily`

Also, under eclipse I can see, when I start wls 11, the state of wls 12 is *stopped, error connecting*

Comment: Both domains use the same cookie name for the administration console, and it could be the cause of this issue. Update one of your domains and set a different cookie name for the admin console. It can be done via the console itself under <domain>/configuration advanced tab.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, 
After removing cookies of the admin console, I successfully login to WL11 server